# Smart Art flow diagram?

Tags: diagrams, smartdiagram

How to make a horizontal flow diagram in latex like:

[image]

If posible i would like some colors in it.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Something like this:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = {Latex[]},
    start chain = going right,
    node distance=7mm,
    block/.style={shape=rectangle, draw,
                  inner sep=1mm, align=center,
                  minimum height=7mm, 
                  join=by ->, on chain}]
%placing the blocks
\node[block] (n1) {Hydraulikstation};
\node[block] (n2) {Kontraventil};
\node[block] (n3) {Cointainer};
\node[block] (n4) {Oliefilter};
\node[block] (n5) {Proportional ventil};
%
\draw[->] (n5.south) --  + (0,-7mm) -| (n1.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Put any colour as you like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = {Latex[]},
    auto,
    start chain = going right,
    node distance=5mm,
    block/.style={shape=rectangle, draw,top color=olive,bottom color=magenta,
                  inner sep=1mm, align=center,
                  minimum height=3em, 
                  join=by ->, on chain}]

   \node[block] (n1) {Hydraulikstation};
   \node[block] (n2) {Kontraventil};
   \node[block] (n3) {Container};
   \node[block] (n4) {Oliefilter};
   \node[block] (n5) {Proportinalventil};
   \draw[->] (n5.south) -- ++(0,-4mm) -| (n1.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
After reading of other (very nice and interesting answers) I recognize, that the coloring is one of wishes in questions ... :-). How to do this, I explained in other answers as well showed in Harish Kumar (thank youu!) hijack of this one. So I will add an example with shadows. In it I also slightly change TikZ (pre)settings: now the style of joins are defined separately, what enable more freedom in their design.

[image]

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                > = {Triangle[]},
      start chain = going right,
    node distance = 7mm,
every join/.style = {->, very thick, gray},
    block/.style={shape=rectangle, draw,
                  inner sep=1mm, align=center,
                  minimum height=7mm, 
                  fill=white, drop shadow,
                  join, on chain}]
%placing the blocks
\node[block] (n1) {Hydraulikstation};
\node[block] (n2) {Kontraventil};
\node[block] (n3) {Cointainer};
\node[block] (n4) {Oliefilter};
\node[block] (n5) {Proportional ventil};
%
\draw[every join] (n5.south) --  + (0,-7mm) -| (n1.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Zarko: I hijacked your answer. Hope you won't mind. :)

Comment: @HarishKumar, now is very colorful :-), Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

For simple diagrams, `smartdiagram` allows you to just list the elements and type of diagram you want. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{back arrow disabled=true}
\smartdiagramadd[flow diagram:horizontal]{%
  Thing 1, Thing 2, Thing 3, Thing 4, Thing 5
}{%
  below of module1/,below of module2/,below of module3/,below of module4/,below of module5/
}
\smartdiagramconnect{<-}{module1/additional-module1.center}
\smartdiagramconnect{-,line cap=round}{additional-module1.center/additional-module5.center}
\smartdiagramconnect{-}{module5/additional-module5.center}
\end{document}
```

[image: smarter flow diagram, possibly]

The colours, arrows etc. can be customised using the package's keys.

If you can have the arrow between the last and first thing above the diagram, it is simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{%
  Thing 1, Thing 2, Thing 3, Thing 4, Thing 5
}
\end{document}
```

[image: simpler case]

Again, colours and arrows can be customised to your liking.

**EDIT** Corrected the gappy arrow in the first version thanks to [Harish Kumar's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271413/smart-art-flow-diagram/271418?noredirect=1#comment652058_271418).

Comment: `line cap=round` in `\smartdiagramconnect{-,line cap=round}{additional-module1.center/additional-module5.center}` will make that connection well connected.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks! That is much improved, I think, even if my solution is still rather hackish ;).

Comment: Anything that produces the required out put is not hacky IMO :) And your idea is good. Actually, I too had a solution similar to yours but I was travelling from college to home. I logged in only to find your code ;-) Nice.

Answer (score 7):

With a small hack into the package code, it is possible to get arrows with the right direction:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\smartdiagramx}{r[] m}{%
    \StrCut{#1}{:}\diagramtype\option
    \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{flow diagram}{% true-flow diagram
        \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]

        \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}  {\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}

        \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
            \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
            \IfStrEq{\option}{horizontal}{% true-horizontal-flow diagram
                \path let \n1 = {int(0-\xi)}, \n2={0+\xi*\sm@core@modulexsep} in
                node[module,drop shadow] (module\xi) at +(\n2,0) {\smitem};
            }{% false-horizontal-flow diagram
            \path let \n1 = {int(0-\xi)}, \n2={0-\xi*\sm@core@moduleysep} in
            node[module,drop shadow] (module\xi) at +(0,\n2) {\smitem};
        }
    }%

    \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{mod(\xi, \maxsmitem) + 1)}
        \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
        \ifnum\xi<\maxsmitem
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{smart diagram arrow back}
        \draw[diagram arrow type] (module\xi) -- (module\xj);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \fi
        % last arrow - not display it in background - check if disabled
        \ifbackarrowdisabled
        \relax
        \else
        \ifnum\xi=\maxsmitem
        \IfStrEq{\option}{horizontal}{% true-horizontal-flow diagram
            \tikzset{square arrow/.style={
                    to path={-- ++(0,-\sm@core@backarrowdistance) -| (\tikztotarget)}
                }
            }
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{smart diagram arrow back}
            \draw[diagram arrow type, square arrow]
            (module\xi.south) to (module\xj.south); % <== 
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        }{% false-horizontal-flow diagram
        \tikzset{square arrow/.style={
                to path={-- ++(\sm@core@backarrowdistance,0) |- (\tikztotarget)}
            }
        }
        \draw[diagram arrow type,square arrow]
        (module\xj.east) to (module\xi);
    }
    \fi
    \fi
}%
\end{tikzpicture}
}{}% end-flow diagram
}   
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \smartdiagramset{set color list={darkgray!90, darkgray!70,gray!70,gray!50,gray!25},
   arrow style=-latex,
   uniform arrow color=true,
   arrow color=gray,
   module x sep=4.5,
   back arrow distance=0.75,
   arrow line width=2.5pt,
   text width =3cm,
 }
 \smartdiagramx[flow diagram:horizontal]{Hydraulikstation,Kontraventil,
    Cointainer,Oliefilter,Proportional ventil}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: It will be nice if the is added as an option in the package: to have the arrow from top (default) and at the bottom (optional).

Comment: @HarishKumar: I was indeed thinking to something like this ;)

Comment: So can we expect it in the next update? :)

Comment: @HarishKumar: Definitely! Hope to have some time and make it soon :)

Comment: This is indeed nice. I couldn't figure out an altogether satisfactory way to do this without delving into the code. At least I wasn't missing something obvious!

Comment: @cfr: Indeed, for this the only way was modifying the original code! But you had a very clever idea with the additions. :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Is there any way to avoid the small gaps I get doing it that way? The lines don't seem to meet quite perfectly.

Comment: @cfr: The motivation is that you are using separate paths (one for each connect). Probably it is necessary to set a style to join better the lines when they interconnect.

Comment: Isn't `Tikz` much simpler than `smartdiagram`?

Comment: @CroCo `smartdiagram` is simpler to use, but TikZ is obviously more flexible because `smartdiagram` is providing you with ready-made TikZ solutions and any recipe book limits your degrees of freedom by design.