# Latex Tikz - Process flow image

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to reproduce such image with Tikz.

[image]

I`ve started writing latex code, and I produced image below:

[image]

And the latex code is below.

I would like to request your help to make my generated picture as similar as possible from the original one.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,shapes.arrows, chains, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=1mm,length=1mm]}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[force/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=black!10, inner sep=5pt,  text badly centered, minimum height=0.5cm, font=\bfseries\sffamily}] 

\node [force] (planejar) {Planejar};
\node [force, right=1cm of planejar] (adquirir) {Adquirir};
\node [force, right=1cm of adquirir] (processar) {Processar};
\node [force, right=1cm of processar] (analisar) {Analisar};
\node [force, right=1cm of analisar] (preservar) {Preservar};
\node [force, right=1cm of preservar] (publicar) {Publicar};
\draw[->, >=latex, black!10!white, line width=10pt]   ([yshift=-1cm]planejar.south) to node[black]{Metadados e Documentação} ([yshift=-1cm]publicar.south);
\draw[->, >=latex, black!10!white, line width=10pt]   ([yshift=-2cm]planejar.south) to node[black]{Gestão da Qualidade} ([yshift=-2cm]publicar.south);
\draw[->, >=latex, black!10!white, line width=10pt]   ([yshift=-3cm]planejar.south) to node[black]{Disponibilidade e Segurança dos Dados} ([yshift=-3cm]publicar.south);

\path[->,thick] 
(planejar) edge (adquirir)
(adquirir) edge (processar)
(processar) edge (analisar)
(analisar) edge (preservar)
(preservar) edge (publicar);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Modelo de ciclo de vida dos dados de pesquisa proposto pela USGS. Adaptado de}
\label{fig:modeloUSG}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!Maybe helpful links for the arrow part: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134178/124842 and the boxes with smart diagramm: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271418/124842

Comment: What does `text badly centered` do? Never seen this used before.

Comment: You can use `shapes.arrows` to get node shapes for the outlined arrows in the top line. I think it will be easiest to get the text closer to just type the text you want directly, rather than typing other text and then finding it doesn't match the target image. That is, I take it you want the text, if you really mean 'as similar as possible'. Otherwise, you obviously shouldn't lie to Babel.

Comment: For the shaded arrows: either use nodes as above or use a scope shading. In the latter case, you can draw the arrows as lines. In the former case, you can simply shade each one as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

is it enough similar?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                fit,
                positioning,
                shapes.arrows}

\usepackage[floats,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
node distance = 10mm and 6mm,
  start chain = A going right,
 force/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, fill=cyan!30,
                 inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm, minimum size=8mm,
                 font=\bfseries\sffamily, on chain},
    CA/.style = {% Connection Arrow
                 single arrow, draw,
                 single arrow head extend=1.5mm,
                 minimum height=6mm, minimum width=5mm, outer sep=0mm},
    LA/.style = {% Long Arrow
                 CA, draw=none, left color=cyan!20, right color=cyan,
                 inner xsep = 6mm, minimum width=9mm, label=center:#1,},
 ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={force}]
\node   {Planejar};     % A-1
\node   {Adquirir};
\node   {Processar};
\node   {Analisar};
\node   {Preservar};
\node   {Publicar};     % A-6
    \end{scope}
% arrows between nodes
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
    \node[CA, right=0mm of A-\i] {};
% long arrows with text
\coordinate[below=of A-1]   (a1);
\coordinate[below=of a1]    (a2);
\coordinate[below=of a2]    (a3);
    \node[LA=Metadados e Documentação,
          fit=(a1) (a1 -| A-6)] {};
    \node[LA=Gestão da Qualidade,
          fit=(a2) (a2 -| A-6)] {};
    \node[LA=Disponibilidade e Segurança dos Dados,
          fit=(a3) (a3 -| A-6)]    {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Modelo de ciclo de vida dos dados de pesquisa proposto pela USGS. Adaptado de}
\label{fig:modeloUSG}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer which takes motivation from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172091/how-to-draw-an-arrow-wide-to-fillcolor) .

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% lets get the exact color
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{B0D7FF}


\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{
    mybox/.style={rectangle,
        draw,
        fill= myblue,
        rounded corners,
        minimum width=2cm,
        inner sep=5pt,
        align=center,
        minimum height=1cm
    },
    myarrow/.style={draw=black,
        fill=white,
        minimum width=0.6cm,
        single arrow
    },
    longarrow/.style={draw=none,
        shading=axis,
        left color=white,
        right color=myblue,
        minimum width=0.6cm,
        single arrow,
        anchor=east
    }
    }


\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]

        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}

        %% Make the boxes
        \node [mybox] (planejar) {Planejar};
        \node [mybox, right=0.7cm of planejar] (adquirir) {Adquirir};
        \node [mybox, right=0.7cm of adquirir] (processar) {Processar};
        \node [mybox, right=0.7cm of processar] (analisar) {Analisar};
        \node [mybox, right=0.7cm of analisar] (preservar) {Preservar};
        \node [mybox, right=0.7cm of preservar] (publicar) {Publicar};

        %% Draw arrows between them
        \node[myarrow] at ([xshift=8pt]planejar.east) {\phantom{\tiny{aaa}}};
        \node[myarrow] at ([xshift=8pt]adquirir.east) {\phantom{\tiny{aaa}}};
        \node[myarrow] at ([xshift=8pt]processar.east) {\phantom{\tiny{aaa}}};
        \node[myarrow] at ([xshift=8pt]analisar.east) {\phantom{\tiny{aaa}}};
        \node[myarrow] at ([xshift=8pt]preservar.east) {\phantom{\tiny{aaa}}};
        \node[myarrow] at ([xshift=8pt]publicar.east) {\phantom{\tiny{aaa}}};

        %% Long arrows
        % reference node
        \node[right=0.3cm of processar](ref){};
        \node[longarrow, below=1cm of ref] (documento)  {\phantom{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa} Metadados e Documentação\phantom{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}};
        \node[longarrow, below=0.7cm of documento] (gestao)  {\phantom{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa} Gestão da Qualidade\phantom{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}};
        \node[longarrow, below=0.7cm of gestao] (dados)  {\phantom{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa} Disponibilidade e Segurança dos Dados\phantom{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}};
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption{Modelo de ciclo de vida dos dados de pesquisa proposto pela USGS. Adaptado de}
        \label{fig:modeloUSG}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This produces:
[image: arrows]